# Can ajax use absolute urls' for calling web services?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

most of the javascript ajax tutorials/example showed that the requests can only be relative path which means cannot call to other web servers.I want to call a web service which is not included in the same application and needs to have an absolute url.when i call something like http://192.168.1.62:8080/TRACER-REST-API/webapi/projects/16/releases/2/issues and the ajax xhr call is something like http:localhost:8080/app/http://192.168.1.62:8080/TRACER-REST-API/webapi/projects/16/releases/2/issues

```js
var XHR = null;

var $ajaxService = (function() {
  function getXHRObject() {

    var xmlHttpObject = null;

    try {
      //for old IE
      xmlHttpObject = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (oldIEException) {

      try {
        // For IE 6.0+
        xmlHttpObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

      } catch (IESixPlusException) {

        xmlHttpObject = false;
      }

    }

    if (!xmlHttpObject && xmlHttpObject !== undefined) {
      // firefox/chrome
      xmlHttpObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlHttpObject;
  }

  return {
    call: function makeServerCall(httpMethod, uri, isAsync, headers, postData, responseCallback) {
      console.log(uri);
      XHR = getXHRObject();
      if (XHR != null) {

        XHR.open(httpMethod, uri, isAsync);
        if (headers != null) {
          //XHR.setRequestHeader();
        }
        if (httpMethod === 'POST' && postData !== undefined) {
          XHR.send(postData);
        } else {
          XHR.send();
        }

        XHR.onreadystatechange = responseHandler(responseCallback);

      }
    }


  }

  function responseHandler(callBack) {
    if (XHR.readyState == 4) {

      switch (XHR.state) {
        case 200:
          callBack();
          break;
        case 500:
          throw new Error("Internal Server Error");
        default:
          throw new Error("Error occurred during server call");
      }

    }

  }

})();
```

Comment: it should be in the same domain

Comment: is it possible to have same host and in different domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can ajax use absolute urls' for calling web services?

Yes, if the receiving server supports a cross origin scheme such as CORS or JSONP and you are specifying the URL properly.

Browsers have a security features called "same origin protection".  By default, this protection allows you to only make Ajax calls to the exact same "origin" (same protocol, same domain, same port) as the web page that the Javascript is running in was loaded from.

There are a couple of ways around this same origin protection.

1. **CORS** - Cross origin resource sharing is a scheme by which the receiving server tells the browser that some or all cross origin requests are allowed.  If the server enables this type of access, then a browser web page from some other domain may make Ajax calls to this service.  CORS is not just all or nothing, it has lots of features so it's even possible for a site to enable only certain types of access or only enable access from certain other sites.
2. **JSONP** - Before CORS existed, the web world came up with a somewhat hackish workaround called JSONP.  In this scheme, the browser requests a script file from the desired host (script files are not subject to same origin security restrictions) and the host server then returns an actual Javascript file that the browser will execute.  If it's done right, the script that executes can then communicate back a result to the caller.  JSONP is not regular Ajax call, though some Ajax libraries (like jQuery) allow you to use their Ajax interface even though you're making a JSONP request.
3. **Proxy** - The same origin restriction is a feature in browsers only so a server can contact any domain it wants without restriction.  One way of working around a same origin restriction is to have your own server (on your own domain that matches the domain of the web page) make the foreign request for you (e.g. proxy the request).  You send an Ajax call to your own server asking it to make a proxied request for you.  Your server then contacts the foreign server, gets the result and returns it back to you as the Ajax response.

---

If you are requesting an Ajax call to a URL like:

`http://192.168.1.62:8080/TRACER-REST-API/webapi/projects/16/releases/2/issues`

and you see that what is actually being used is 
`http:localhost:8080/app/http://192.168.1.62:8080/TRACER-REST-API/webapi/projects/16/releases/2/issues`

Then something is likely wrong with your code because the browser will not do this by itself if your code is correct.  You will probably have to show us your actual code for us to see where your code is going wrong.  Absolute URIs are supported if specified properly.

---

In your Ajax code, you need to make several changes:

**1) Implicit Global**.  Add `var` here so `XHR` isn't an accidental global variable and so you won't have a variable conflict if you are doing more than one Ajax call at a time:

```
var XHR = getXHRObject();
```

**2) Fix XHR.onreadystatechange**.  Change this:

```
XHR.onreadystatechange = responseHandler(responseCallback);
```

to this so you aren't calling it immediately, but are assigning a function that can be called later:

```
XHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
    responseHandler(XHR, responseCallback);
}
```

And, then add the extra XHR argument to your `responseHandler()` implementation.

**3) Fix error handling.** It does you no good to `throw` from within your `responseHandler()` function.  That is an async callback and doing a `throw` there will just throw into the bowels of the XMLHttpRequest infrastructure.  It will not be an exception you can use for anything meaningful.  You will likely need to restructure your code so that you communicate errors back to the caller via the callback.

**4) Use an already tested Ajax library.** In this day and age, I have no idea why you're writing your own Ajax wrapper from scratch.  There are literally thousands of them already available you can just pull off the shelf, copy into your project and not have to go through solving all these types of problems with your own code.  If I personally wasn't already using any framework that had Ajax support, I'd probably go get a polyfill for the new `fetch()` API and use that since that's the future of client-side Ajax and it's a nice clean API.

Comment: @GayanPrasanna - We would need to see the code where you call your ajax function and see exactly what URLs you are passing to it.  Also, there are several coding mistakes in your Ajax code.  I will add some comments about them to my answer.

Comment: with your fixes i solved my problems and the issue was my url is having whitespaces and some stuffs after fixed it and made your changes it worked perfectly.I have been asked not to use any frameworks or libraries for this works,that's why I wrote a wrapper for ajax

Answer (score 1):

Call a CURL script via AJAX:

JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "assets/php/some_script.php",
    type: 'GET',
    path: //object to send to CURL request,            
    timeout: 1500,
    cache: false,         
    error: function(a, b, c){
        console.log("Error:", a, b, c);
    },
    success: function(data){
        //work with your data here
    }
});
```

PHP (i.e. some_script.php):

```
$path = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'path');
$url = /*Your absolute URL here*/ . $path

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$json = curl_exec($ch);

if ($error = curl_error($ch)) {
    trigger_error("Failed to communicate with server: {$error}", E_USER_ERROR);
    return;
}
curl_close($ch);
return $json;
```

Comment: thanks for the help.But I am not using php .thanks anyway